# This if or that if in contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

dunno can I write one more question about contact form but i will try :) Maybe u will help faster ;p

Code:

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $from = 'From: domain.com'; 
 $to = 'dawid@domain.com'; 
 $subject = 'Message from domain.com';

 $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

   if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {
               echo '<p class="msg">Wrong email adress!!!</p>';
        }            

        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {               
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                        echo '<p class="msg">Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else { 
                        echo '<p class="msg">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                       } 
                } else {
                        echo '<p class="msg">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
                       }
    }
?>
```

And as u can see i have here few messages (echos) in if statements. But I wanna make this to display just one echo even if there would be more errors in contact form... Is that possible ?

example:
Somebody leave all inputs empty and click "send" - atm he would get msg about wrong email and "u need fill all required fields".
But in this kind os situation firstly i would like to display just msg about empty fields and after that if for example somebody would write wrong email another msg about wrong email :D Hope u understand what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if (!$email) {
        echo '<p class="msg">Email is required.</p>';
    }
    elseif (!$name) {
        echo '<p class="msg">Name is required.</p>';
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
        echo '<p class="msg">Wrong email adress!!!</p>';
    }
    elseif ($name != '' && $email != '') {

        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p class="msg">Your message has been sent!</p>';
        }
        else { 
            echo '<p class="msg">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    }
    else {
        echo '<p class="msg">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }

}
```

Comment: when fields are empty and I click send message shows "email is wrong" exept of "fill all the fields" :D

Comment: That's because in your code, you are first checking to see if the email matches your expression.  And then it will stop processing errors.  So it's never making it to another part where you check to see if the email is set.  If you want to check that first, then make the existing `if (!preg_match...` an `elseif (!preg_match...` and make a new `if (!$email) {echo 'Email is required';}` before it.  PHP will process them in order of top to bottom.

Comment: Could I one more time ask u to write whole code ? :D hehehe thanks a lot man u r great that u r helping me with that crappy contact form :P

Comment: I just added a check for name and email to the top of the conditional block.  You can just keep adding in checks like that.  As many `elseif` statements as you wish.  It will still only print out one item.

Comment: I've edited ur code a little bit but now it works perfect !!! Now tell me what can I do for u for that help ? :D Is here any option to give u a poiint recommend or something ? :P

Comment: Yes, accept my answer.  That will give me points.  And you are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($name == '' || $email == '' || $message == '') {               
 echo '<p class="msg">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
}else if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)){
 echo '<p class="msg">Wrong email adress!!!</p>';
}else if (!mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
 echo '<p class="msg">Your message has not been sent!</p>';
}else{
 echo '<p class="msg">Your message has been sent!</p>';
}
```

Comment: it is not exactly what I want but it's close... now when i click send I see just and only one message... but after click send the contact form disapear 0.o and i see just message ;D So even that i can't correct my contact form without refresh the whole site ;D

Comment: now it's almost good I edited a little bit this code:

if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {               
 echo '<p class="msg">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
}else if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)){
 echo '<p class="msg">Wrong email adress!!!</p>';
}else if (!mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
 echo '<p class="msg">Your message has not been sent!</p>';
}else{
 echo '<p class="msg">Your message has been sent!</p>';
}

but dunno why when all fields are empty i see message about wrong email lol :C

Comment: @DaVv How about now ?

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of errors and then implode that array to display the complete error message.

```
// DEFAULT
$errors = array();

// CHECK THINGS FOR ERRORS AND ADD THEM TO THE ERROR ARRAY
if ((!$name) || ($name == '')) {
    $errors[] = '* Name is required';
}

if ((!$email) || ($email == '')) {
    $errors[] = '* Email is required';
}

// ... etc. - Anything else you want caught in an error

// IF WE HAVE ERRORS, TURN THEM INTO A STRING AND PRINT THEM
if ($errors) {
    $error_message = implode('<br>', $errors);
    echo $error_message;
}
```

EDIT: 
Per request of OP, here is the example that was asked for.

```
// CHECK THINGS FOR ERRORS AND ADD THEM TO THE ERROR ARRAY
if ((!$name) || ($name == '')) {
    $errors = '* Name is required';
}

if ((!$email) || ($email == '')) {
    $errors = '* Email is required';
}

// ... etc. - Anything else you want caught in an error

// IF WE HAVE ERRORS, PRINT THEM
if ($errors) {
    echo $error_message;
}
```

** Note: You can achieve the same thing (and it would make more sense to do so) by using conditional statements.  Only one condition can be evaluated as true, so once it finds a match, it will not go into any other 'elseif' statements.

Comment: yeah but than it will shows for example two errors if there will be two... i want to have one message max on the screen... like I wrote... if somebody dont write anything i want message something like "fill all the require fields" and if somebody for example write everything but wrong email i want to display just aqnd only message about "wrong email"

Comment: Okay, then you can do the same thing as above except instead of assigning errors to an array, you can assign them to a variable. `$errors = '* Name is required';`.  Each time an error occurs (if there are multiple errors), that variable will be overwritten with the latest error message.  So there will only ever be one error in that variable.

Comment: could u write an example for me ? :D I would be greatful :)

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer to include a string version.  You should probably use conditionals like you did initially, except you can only have one 'else'.  All of the others should be 'elseif'.  `if (xxxx) {} elseif (yyyy) {} else {}`

Comment: damn it still isnt work well... maybe it's not so easy to implement : D

Comment: this code isnt work at all :D when i click send nothing happends... :P Anyway you think there is not possible to change something in my first code to be like i would like to >

Comment: Yeah, just fix your if/elseif/else statements.  You can only have one 'else'.

Comment: I will make a new answer for you.

Comment: in which places shall I put else if and where else haha :D I hate php mehh :D

Comment: Please see my other answer in this post.

Comment: oh u wrote the code bellow... tested this but still... when fields are empty and i click send i can see msg - "wrong email" exept of "fill all the fields"

Answer (score -1):

I still think that it's possible to edit this code as it should work as i want... but dont know how ;D

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $from = 'From: domain.com'; 
 $to = 'dawid@domain.com'; 
 $subject = 'Message from domain.com';

 $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

   if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {
               echo '<p class="msg">Wrong email adress!!!</p>';
        }            

        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {               
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                        echo '<p class="msg">Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else { 
                        echo '<p class="msg">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                       } 
                } else {
                        echo '<p class="msg">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
                       }
    }
?>
```

maybe put this error about mail in other place or something ? or any else if ? help <3